# How to search for a branch in a Project in Private Gitlab Setup?

Tags: git, gitlab

We have an organisation wide private Gitlab setup. It has a project containing more than 1200 branches (not the way, right?). Now I need to search for a particular branch in it, How do I do that?

[image: All I can see is a Sort branches option]

Comment: What is the version of your GitLab? It the newest one search input is near `New branch` button.

Comment: @Piotr the version number is "8.7.3 1d72f95"

Answer (score 0):

If you know the branch name, go to

`http(s)://<Your Gitlab Url>/<Org Name>/<Project Name>/tree/<Branch Name>`

Basically just append `/tree/<Branch Name>` to the URL from where you took the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep, I already know this way, but I don't know the exact branch name, that's the reason I needed search.